# addClass à um elemento a cima da hierarquia

Tags: jquery, addclass

Segue demonstração do que estou tentando fazer..

HTML

```
<div id="conteudo">   
<div id="inner" class="move">
        <div class="col-md-10"><a class="botao" href="#">botao</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">22222</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $( ".botao" ).click(function( {
$( "#inner" ).addClass( "move-left" );
});
    );
```

CSS

```
#conteudo{overflow:hidden;width:100%;position;relative;height:200px;}     
#inner{height:200px;width:120%;}
    .move{left:0;position:relative;}
    .move-left{left:-20%;position:relative;background:#000!important}
    .col-md-10{width:80%;position:relative;float:left;}
    .col-md-2{width:20%;position:relative;float:left;}
    .botao{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35DJy/387/

quero que quando clicar no botado o conteudo do `col-md-2` venha para esquerda, e quando clicado fora desse elemento, retire a classe `move-left`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma mais explícita, você pode usar o `.closest()` para modificar quaisquer elemento acima na hierarquia. A vantagem sobre o `.parent()` é que você não precisa encadear vários `.parent()` até chegar no elemento desejado, pois o `.closest()` varre toda a árvore hierárquica recursivamente até chegar no elemento que atende aos critérios informados. Com base na sua questão, o exemplo seria:

Pegando pelo ID:

```
$( "a.botao" ).click(function() {
   $(this).closest('#inner').addClass( "move-left" );
});
```

Ou pegando pela classe:

```
$( "a.botao" ).click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.move').addClass( "move-left" );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Para acessar o elemento acima na hierarquia você pode usar a função [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```js
$( "a.botao" ).click(function() {
   $( "#inner" ).parent().addClass( "move-left" );
});
```

```css
#inner
.move{background:none;}
.move-left{background:#000}
.botao{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inner" class="move">
    <a class="botao" href="#">botao</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Agora como faço para retirar a classe que foi inserida caso o usuario clique em qualquer area da tela que não seja o col-md-2?

Comment: @manzetti.denis Que não tenha a classe `col-md-2` ou que não esteja *contido* em um elemento com classe `col-md-2`?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, ve se está mais claro...

Comment: @manzetti.denis Nesse caso acho melhor você fazer uma nova pergunta. Isso vai mudar basicamente a resposta toda.